# Manipulating position of child div inside parent div and the problems they entail

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I wanna position the h1 and button at around bottom: 40% and left: 20% i.e hovering over the bottom left side of the parent div(id="head). Using display: abolute; and positioning tags makes them go outside the screen when the screen size is changed. Is there any other way other than positiong method or without using flex or grid cause i have another div which gets affected when i change display to flex/grid. Thank You.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body{
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: #fff 3px solid;
    padding: 1.3rem 2.3rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.button:hover{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    border: black 3px solid;
}


#head{
    position: relative;
    /* background-image: url(/images/snow-capped-mountains-under-the-cloudy-skies-1054289.jpg); */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#head .show-top {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}


.show-top li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.show-top a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}


#head .showcase{
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#head .showcase h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 5rem;
    /* padding: 2rem; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="head" style="border: violet 5px solid;">
        <div class="show-top">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="showcase" style="border: turquoise 5px solid;">
            <h1>Take a step</h1>
            <a href="#" class="button">Enter</a>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quiet sure what your final desired outcome is. But this works at my end:

Making the parent absolute and the `showcase` relative to its parent. If you resize your window the measures/position ratio stays the same.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body{
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: #fff 3px solid;
    padding: 1.3rem 2.3rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.button:hover{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    border: black 3px solid;
}


#head{
    position: absolute;
    /* background-image: url(/images/snow-capped-mountains-under-the-cloudy-skies-1054289.jpg); */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#head .show-top {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}


.show-top li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 1rem;
}

.show-top a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}


.showcase{
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 50vw;    
}

.showcase h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 20vw;
    /* padding: 2rem; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="head" style="border: violet 5px solid;">
        <div class="show-top">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="showcase" style="border: turquoise 5px solid;">
            <h1>Take a step</h1>
            <a href="#" class="button">Enter</a>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using margin:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


body{
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: #fff 3px solid;
  padding: 1.3rem 2.3rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2.2rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.button:hover{
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  border: black 3px solid;
}


#head{
  position: relative;
  /* background-image: url(/images/snow-capped-mountains-under-the-cloudy-skies-1054289.jpg); */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#head .show-top {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}


.show-top li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.show-top a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}


#head .showcase{
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

#head .showcase h1{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5rem;
  /* padding: 2rem; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="head" style="border: violet 5px solid;">
        <div class="show-top">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROGRAMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="showcase" style="border: turquoise 5px solid;">
            <h1>Take a step</h1>
            <a href="#" class="button">Enter</a>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>

</html>
```